# Local name collision

Tags: php, fedora, httpd

Me aparecen esta serie de errores, y no encuentro una solución, he podido leer que no solo hay que crear un ***VirtualHost***, sino que también hay que especificarlo en **/etc/hosts**.

Todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde una máquina virtual con *Fedora 25*.

> [Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.768376 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3031] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
>
> [Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.772153 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3031] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
>
> [Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.859442 2017] [:error] [pid 3032] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("nombre_usuario") failed: Local name collision
>
> [Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.864701 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3031] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2j-fips PHP/5.6.29 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.864740 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3031] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Answer (score 0):

El único error que se ve es:

> "[Sun Jan 22 20:03:51.859442 2017] [:error] [pid 3032]
>   avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("nombre_usuario") failed: Local
>   name collision"

Y seguramente pertenece a un módulo de terceros, no propio de httpd ¿mod_php quizás?

No es necesario que pongas ninguna entrada en /etc/hosts.

Pero hay dos cosas a tener en cuenta:

- Si llamas a tu website por un nombre, el cliente que lo llame tendrá que ser capaz de resolver el nombre correctamente, o bien por DNS o bien por Host, pero esto es de lógica, a httpd le da exactamente igual, podrías acceder directamente por ip. En resumen, la resolución de nombres es tu responsabilidad.
- No es necesario generar un virtualhost, pero si lo defines, el primer virtualhost gestionará todas las peticiones que reciba, heredará las configuraciones base de la configuración del servidor y el resto las sobreescribirá con lo que tenga definido el propio virtualhost.
- Lo recomendable es que cada virtualhost tenga su directiva ServerName con el nombre de host asignado al que tiene que contestar y/o si tiene varios nombres, añadirlos con la directiva Serveralias.

Aquí tienes unos ejemplos de [configuración mínima](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Minimal_Config) en httpd. Estos van sin virtualhost.

Por último, y como recomendación no deberías usar `mod_php` y en apache deberías usar `mpm_event`.